# Defacement/Censorship of peoples answers

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-answer

yesterday the following edit was made https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/33730/revisions which deletes content from an (very old) answer. Taking liberty to edit and perform such censorship/deletion seems not appropriate as it is not community wiki. He should have rolled back rather than deleted bit the he doesn't like.

And now someone else did it https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/33730/revisions

Comment: agreed. I will roll back.

Comment: Many thanks to robjohn, Did and Zev.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for keeping an eye out for things like this. For what it is worth, in the future, it suffices to flag the post in question for moderator attention; it is not necessary to open up a discussion on Meta.

Comment: The answer was locked, and a notice was added. "Community" unlocked it and removed the notice. Is this the work of a person, or automatic/software?

Comment: The imposed lock was a timed-lock, [which can be set for a fixed period](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6796/more-granularity-in-locking-questions). After the period expires, the community user automatically unlocks the post.